# How can I maintain two separate projects but merge them into one DLL?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ilmerge

I'm hoping that there is just something simple that I am missing here. I am trying to maintain two separate projects

```
ProjectName.Core &
ProjectName.Infrastructure
```

This is made in a typical Onion architecture so I can loosely couple my services and gain a greater flexibility. The Infrastructure project references the Core project. Once compiled they generate these DLLs

```
ProjectName.Core.dll &
ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll
```

But I would like to have it generate just 1 dll.

```
ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll (or even ProjectName.dll)
```

I have tried to use ILMerge to perform this operation but since Infrastructure references Core it throws an exception because it can't find the Core dll. It's obviously not looking within itself.

Now I need to maintain the separate projects because I have some other combinations that reference Core and another project that will be joined together such as

```
ProjectName.Core &
ProjectName.DataAccess &
ProjectName.Web
```

**EDIT**: My current solution calls out to ILMerge using an Nant build script. It merged together successfully. But when I try to use the merged DLL it throws an exception because it can't find the Core library.

```
  <target name="merge.core">
    <property name="temp.dir" value="${build.dir}\Temp\"/>
    <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}" if="${not directory::exists(temp.dir)}"/>
    <property name="tools.dir" value="&quot;${directory::get-current-directory()}\Tools\&quot;"/>
    <exec program="Tools\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" workingdir=".">
      <arg value="/t:Library"/>
      <arg value="/ndebug"/>      
      <arg value="/out:&quot;${build.dir}\Temp\ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll&quot;"/>
      <arg value="&quot;${build.dir}ProjectName.Core.dll&quot;"/>
      <arg value="&quot;${build.dir}Xceed.Compression.dll&quot;"/>
      <arg value="&quot;${build.dir}ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll&quot;"/>
      <arg value="&quot;${build.dir}ProjectName.Infrastructure.XmlSerializers.dll&quot;"/>
    </exec>
    <delete file="${build.dir}ProjectName.Core.dll"/>
    <delete file="${build.dir}Xceed.Compression.dll"/>
    <delete file="${build.dir}ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll"/>
    <delete file="${build.dir}ProjectName.Infrastructure.XmlSerializers.dll"/>
    <move file="${build.dir}\Temp\ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll" tofile="${build.dir}ProjectName.Infrastructure.dll"/>
    <delete dir="${temp.dir}" if="${directory::exists(temp.dir)}"/>
  </target>
```

To be a little more clear. I can use objects out of the Core library but not the Infrastructure library. Because once it tries to instantiate one of those objects it seems .NET attempts to load the dependency but cannot find it.

Comment: Or you could just ship two DLL's and be done with it.  Just saying...

Comment: This is also true. We certainly ship with all the DLLs today and I'm trying to simplify it for the users.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). It works out of the box to do this.

Answer (score 2):

ILMerge!  Almost as good as sliced bread.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As I know that is not possible in Visual Studio, but you can compile every project as a netmodule and then join them together as a DLL. Compile like this:

```
csc misource1.cs misource2.cs misource3.cs /target:module
```

and then link together with the al.exe tool, see [.netmodule Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k669k83h(VS.80).aspx) and [C# Assemblies](http://tools.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Development/C-Assemblies/).

Comment: Yes. I can also specify everything as part of my Nant build script. But I want to avoid extra work of maintaining the script and the MSBUILD project files for each project.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of ILMerge has a `/closed` option which works on the transitive closure of the merged assemblies. It solves this exact problem (see sections `2.6 Closed` and `4.1 Input assembly not merged in correctly` in the ILMerge.doc user manual).

Note that if your library attempts to dynamically load objects from a *named* assembly, then it would not work because the merged assembly name is different than the original assembly name. There isn't anything ILMerge can do in this case; you'll have to modify your dependency injection to account for this.